# Table with Int Clustered Identity & NVarChar Primary Key - Which one do I join to?

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key, clustered-index

My table structure looks something like this:

**USER**:

```
UserId int - clustered index & identity
UserName nvarchar - PK
Name nvarchar
Location nvarchar
```

**USER TYPE JOIN**

```
UserName nvarchar - PK
UserTypeId int - PK
```

**USER TYPE**

```
UserTypeId int - PK
Name nvarchar
```

Originally my `User` table didn't have the `UserId` and I was using the `UserName` as the primary key as well as the identity and clustered index column, but that was causing me fragmentation issues so I added `UserId` and set it to the clustered index identity.

So now I'm wondering if I need to change my join table `UserName` column to the `UserId` as it's the table identity and I'm thinking it might improve performance, or is it best to leave it on the `UserName` because it's the primary key?

I've tried looking on google for an answer to this, but I can't come up with anything relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Using an Int as the primary key and doing all joins based on that columns will be faster than using the UserName especially since you have a clustered index on that column.

You probably should change all of your joins to use the UserId and make that column the primary key.  You can put a Unique Constraint on the UserName field to ensure that column remains Unique.

Answer (score 0):

Joining on UserId may well make some queries more efficient but be aware that there could also be costs associated with referencing UserId instead of UserName. You may end up needing to do joins where you didn't have to before because the UserName now resides only in the User table. Also you'll probably need additional application and data tier code to handle the mapping and translation between UserNames and UserIds - assuming the UserName is still what the users care about and what your business logic is dependent on. I suggest you evaluate the overall impact before deciding whether to make the change.

Many people invariably put the PRIMARY KEY constraint on whatever key columns are being referenced by foreign keys in other tables; other people prefer that a "natural key" is always designated PRIMARY KEY. It mostly comes down to convention and aesthetics and doesn't necessarily make any practical difference either way. I've certainly not noticed that query performance in SQL Server is ever affected by using a PRIMARY KEY constraint instead of a UNIQUE constraint.